# What's wrong with my array.filter syntax?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
this.firmCategories = this.firmCategories.filter(x => {
  x.id !== firmCatId;
});
```

I can see that there is one element of the firmCategories array that has the matching ID by using my debugger, however, I am left with a completely empty array after this executes.

I would expect to have every element except for the one that has the matching ID leftover.  What's up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing a `return` statement.

```
this.firmCategories = this.firmCategories.filter(x => {
    return x.id !== firmCatId;
});
```

Or take an arrow function without a function body.

```
this.firmCategories = this.firmCategories.filter(x => x.id !== firmCatId);
```

Comment: Formatted it like that in order to debug, but so you can't use a function body with the lambda.  Never would've guessed, thank you!